# Update label in method iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a label in my storyboard, i am setting text to my label in `viewDidLoad`, but when i call my method, label is not updating. I am calling my method1 when my scrollview is scrolling.

Here is my code example;

```
//.h
NSString *text;

//.m

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

[self method1];    

}
-(void) method1{

text = @"Here is the text";

NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
[runloop addTimer:timer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];

}

-(void) updateLabel{

label.text = text;

}
```

What should i do for updating my label? Thanks.

Comment: Have you wired up your label to an `IBOutlet`in your view controller?

Comment: Do you ever execute the `updateLabel` method?

Comment: is text an ivar.... I see this `text = @"a";` in -(void) changeDiscount:(int)currentPagePresentation{ and `label.text = text`; in a different method

Comment: @HotLicks yeah updateLabel method is working.

Comment: set a breakpoint and make sure that text is really `a` when it gets into that method. And of course make sure its not null

Comment: @Marco yeah i wired up like that @ property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

Comment: @user3255346 that will set it up but you do still need to wire it up in Interface Builder

Comment: @user3255346 could it be that updateLabel is not being called on the main thread?

Comment: @logixologist "a" is coming in my updateLabel method, i can't set my label.

Comment: Try and wrap the `label.text = text;` in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... });` block.

Comment: did you go into IB and drag from your label to File Owner. If you can see "A" in label.text = text; and its not showing on your screen, then its not really wired up correctly. Try removing the connection and re-wire it.

Comment: i also tried this way [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector() withObject: waitUntilDone:];

Comment: Did you clean your project?

Comment: @logixologist i just tried, it didn't work :( and also i deleted my label and created new one, result is same

Comment: ok how are you "wiring it up" I assume you are using IB?

Comment: This is ridiculous, 20 minutes in and we are still trying to find out whether the OP has *wired it up* to IB properly or not. @user3255346 Mate, update your question so that you paste your code properly, I believe this is incomplete code. You have not even defined what `text` is. Help us so that we can help you!

Comment: Yeah i am using storyboard, firstly i put a label on view and i right click my label and i dragged to .h file and i gave a name. isn't that right?

Comment: @Pavan, if in the setting label step, if the variable being set to the text property is showing up, its one of 2 things, the label is still null, or the label is not wired up correctly. So yes we are going to find out if its wired correctly.

Comment: Put a stop on `label.text = text;`, and when you get there do `po label` and `po text`.  Make sure that `label` is non-nil and that `text` is set the way you think it should be.

Answer (score 2):

You need to control-drag your label object to your implementation (viewControllerClass.m) file using the Counterparts split pane view in Xcode, and you should give it a meaningful name ('label' alone is quite vague).

Then you can set the text using:

```
someLabel.text = @"some text";
```

Then you can try setting the text by using a declared NSString variable:

```
NSString *labelText = @"some text";
someLabel.text = labelText;
```

If this doesn't work, go back to IB and open the Utilities pane. Show the connections inspector (far right) to confirm it has the correct referencing outlet (someLabel - viewControllerClass). You might have wired it up twice, accidentally.

Comment: I looked in inspector, there is only one label in Outlets part.

Comment: Does this work for you?
someLabel.text = @"some text";